# Events sheet is not auto-updated to the newest date

Tags: date, events, google-bigquery

Why my events sheet in Big Query are not updated to Jan 13,2020? It's still Dec 30,2019. I can't see the newest event sheet. Aren't they auto updated to the newest date with time passing?

Comment: Your question seems vague. Are you trying to say that you have external table which references to google sheet called events? The sheet is updated in location but the contents in table is not refreshed?

Comment: Thank for your attention. You know we can see our project events data in the big query and these events sheet can be listed by each days. But in my dashboard, my events date is not updated to the newest days, it's still stay at Dec.30 1919. I confirm that another project event date can be presented till now, I don't know why my event date is not updated with time passing.

Comment: What's an events sheet? Who provided this data source?

Comment: In the Firebase homepage, you can see ‘event’ in the left column, and then click ‘view in bigquery’ at the bottom of 'event' page.  If you have a project in bigquery, you can see ‘event’ sheet in the 'analytics' at the left side of bigquery page. 'event' data can be checked each day with time passing and auto-created by itself. But my 'event' date is not updated to the newest date from january. It still stays on Dec.30.2019. Now is Jan.15.2020.  I don't know what problem with it? Should I do some operation to update the date?

Comment: Have you made any recent changes to your Firebase plan? In some cases this can result in the data streaming stopping. If this is the case, it can be fixed by [unlinking](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#unlink) and then [linking](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#link) your Firebase project to BigQuery.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion very much. I'll try it immediately. Sincerely thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if that solution works for you. In that case I would post it as an answer so that it may be useful for future contributors.

Comment: I‘m sorry for the delay. I tried to unlink and then link to BigQuery, but there is still no recent datas in my 'event' sheet in the 'analytics'. I don't know how to deal with the problems. So sad.

Comment: Another possible cause could be issues with a Firebase service account. The account firebase-setup@system.gserviceaccount.com should have the BigQuery Data Editor IAM role within your project. If it does not, please [grant the role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) to the aforementioned account. I hope this works for you.